# getting syntax error: unexpected end of file in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

This is my code:

```
 #!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        echo "No arguments passed: valid usage is script.sh filename"
else if [[ ! -f "$1" ]]; then
        echo "file does not exists"
else
        for i in {558..2005};
        do
                if [[ ! -d "/abc" ]]; then
                        mkdir /abc
                fi
                mkdir /abc/xyz$i
                cp $1 /abc/xyz$i/$1
        done
fi
```

my error: can anyone please help me i do not know what to do? I do not know where I am making mistake?

```
./script.sh: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Use `elif` not `else if`.

Comment: Try out [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net). It helpfully says "[Use 'elif'](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1075) instead of 'else if' (or put 'if' on new line if nesting)."

Comment: Thanks That Worked for me

Comment: I'm not able to find any duplicates for this issue. @MichalH do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126752/what-is-the-difference-between-else-if-and-elif-in-bash is sorta' a duplicate, insofar as it asks the differences between the forms, and the answer (correctly) states that an extra `fi` is required when using `else if` instead of `elif`; communicating that difference _does_ answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `elif` instead of `else if`.

Syntax of `if` in bash:

```
if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a single `if` statement with an `elif` clause, you nested a second `if` statement in the `else` clause of the first, but only terminated the second one. Your code, reformatted to highlight the issue, is

```
if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    echo "No arguments passed: valid usage is script.sh filename"
else
    if [[ ! -f "$1" ]]; then
        echo "file does not exists"
    else
        for i in {558..2005};
        do
            if [[ ! -d "/abc" ]]; then
                mkdir /abc
            fi
            mkdir /abc/xyz$i
            cp $1 /abc/xyz$i/$1
        done
    fi
```

Notice the lack of a second `fi` which would terminate the outer `if` statement.

Using `elif`, your code becomes

```
if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    echo "No arguments passed: valid usage is script.sh filename"
elif [[ ! -f "$1" ]]; then
    echo "file does not exists"
else
    for i in {558..2005};
    do
        if [[ ! -d "/abc" ]]; then
            mkdir /abc
        fi
        mkdir /abc/xyz$i
        cp $1 /abc/xyz$i/$1
    done
fi
```

The `elif` clause doesn't require a closing `fi`; it is implicitly terminated by the following `else` clause.